# Create map of intersection output

Tags: r

I have two datasets.

One is a CSV file, which has a listing of Airbnb in New York. Is from that website: http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data And NY Zipcodes from that website: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Business/Zip-Code-Boundaries/i8iw-xf4u/data?no_mobile=true

I did now an intersection

```
ny <- read.csv("NY/listings.csv")
zc <-  st_read("ZIP_CODE_040114/ZIP_CODE_040114.shp")
nysf <- st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs="epsg:2263")
nysf = st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs="EPSG:4326")
nysft = st_transform(nysf, st_crs(zc))
inters = st_intersects(nysft,zc)
```

now I would like to create a map using tmap, which shows the number of listings in a zipcode. I wanted to convert inters as a dataframe but then the length was reduced.

I started like this

```
tm_shape(nysft)
```

but don't know how to add the count in a zipcode

The goal is to show how many listings are within a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the task correctly, but I suggest the following solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tmap)  

ny <- read_csv("listings.csv")
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 39881 Columns: 75
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (25): listing_url, source, name, description, neighborhood_overview, pi...
#> dbl  (37): id, scrape_id, host_id, host_listings_count, host_total_listings_...
#> lgl   (8): host_is_superhost, host_has_profile_pic, host_identity_verified, ...
#> date  (5): last_scraped, host_since, calendar_last_scraped, first_review, la...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
zc <-  read_sf("ZIP_CODE_040114.shp")
nysf <- st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs=4326)
nysf <- st_transform(nysf, 2263)
inters <- st_intersection(nysf,zc)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

zipcode_count <- inters %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(id, ZIPCODE) %>% 
  group_by(ZIPCODE) %>% 
  count()

zc2 <- zc %>% 
  left_join(zipcode_count)
#> Joining, by = "ZIPCODE"

tm_shape(zc2)+
  tm_polygons()+
  tm_text("n", size = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that I have the files directly in the working directory (you need to adjust the paths).